# Hidden area for secret files in Android phone

Tags: android, file, hide

When I download a pdf file from the Android app, I do not want the user to be able to find it on the phone. Is there such a hidden space on Android phones? I have tried putting a dot in the folder or trying other solutions from the internet but they can reach the windows computers when the phone is connected to the computer via cable. Is there anyone who can suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid having that file on the external storage completely.

Simply use `getFilesDir()` for that.

Answer (score -1):

Use the device's internal storage as described in the android docs.

Files stored on the internal storage are only visible to your app and removed when your app is uninstalled.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html